# I'm trying to use 2 scroll views but I can see one but not the other

Tags: android-studio, android-scrollview

I'm trying to use 2 scroll views, one for some text to be scrolled vertically and another for footnote to be scrolled horizontally. Both of these XML files are included in content_mail.xml but I cannot see the second text view (the one to be used as footnote). 
content_mail.xml includes both the xml files section_scroll_layout.xml & footnote_scroll_layout.xml but I can only see the output of code written in section_scroll_layout.xml; not the second xml file in the preview as well as the apk in my phone. Thank you for your time. Below is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.divya.niluv1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
 R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_favourites) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_aboutus) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_privacy) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
   }

}
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout



xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_scroll"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="291dp"
    android:layout_height="355dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2">

    <include layout="@layout/section_scroll_layout" />

    <include layout="@layout/footnote_scroll_layout" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="146dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="Title"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

section_scroll_layout.xml (First textview that scrolls vertically)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingLeft="8dp"
          android:paddingRight="8dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp">

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"

            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text=" Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. TEXT ENDS HERE. ABOVE TEXT WRITTEN THRICE NOW." />

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</merge>
```

footnote_scroll_layout.xml (Second textview that scrolls horizontally)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"

            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text=" Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book." />
        </ScrollView>

    </HorizontalScrollView>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</merge>
```